# No module named tensorflow found in Windows 10 64bit version

Tags: python-3.x

After installing Tensorflow with cpu support, I am getting some problems in the verification of Tensorflow.
I don't have any GPU in my laptop and used `pip3`  for installation

Comment: Thanks for your concern

Comment: I am done with that

Answer (score 0):

Pls, explain a little more *where* you're getting that error also it's quite possible that code you're using for verification is using codes which involve GPU. Hit me back on this one.